# Java 5 runtime in Java 6 Hotspot

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Is there a way to run Java 6's Hotspot with Java 5's runtime environment?  I have some code that depends on the behavior of older implementations of classes, but I'd like to use a more recent JVM.  I do have plans to migrate the code to Java 6 (or maybe 7!), but right now, I'm more concerned with seeing if I have a JVM issue.

Comment: Curious to know what older implementations you depend on.

Comment: Well I hope it's not relying on Java 5's ability to encode NUL (EOF) characters into Strings. That causes no end of hilarity (when your DB driver stuffs up); eclipse's debug will show all chars up to the NUL, but if you expand out, the rest of the String is there. You can edit/iterate all the characters in Java, but as soon as you try to stream it anywhere else ... guess what?

Comment: Sun used Xalan (with some modifications) as its XSLT implementation.  One of the 5 updates included an updated Xalan with a bug that causes my stylesheets to not compile.

Now that I think about it, maybe I should just rebuild rt.jar with the old version of Xalan and add it to the extensions directory.

Comment: Have you found exactly were this bug is ? You could isolate which classes are involved in this bug, recompile them after fixing it (decompile it or get the right version from the official website) and finally inject these updated .class(es) in rt.jar (overriding the previous ones).

Comment: It's somewhere near com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal, but Xalan is supposed to be paired with a compatible Xerces version.  I could rebuild rt.jar, but extdir seems more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off with one of the following:

- Figure out if you can modify your application code to work around the XSLT bug in Java 6.
- Find out if there is a Sun/Oracle supported patch for the XSLT bug on Java 6.
- Use a Java 5 JRE.
- Try the latest Java 6 JRE to see if the XSLT bug is fixed there.
- Try the latest Java 7 JRE to see if the XSLT bug is fixed there.

The problem with using a Java 5 `rt.jar` on a Java 6 JVM is that there are hidden dependencies between core classes in the `rt.jar` and the native code implementation of the JVM; i.e. `java` binary and associated native libraries.  These are not documented, and it is (IMO) highly likely that some of them changed between Java 5 and Java 6.

---

> If there are native incompatibilities between the two, it looks like I'm left with grabbing the specific classes I need and either replacing them in rt.jar or overriding them with extdir.

Hacking Java like that is not a good idea. At a minimum, you'll have to repeat the hackery each time you download and install the latest Java 6 JRE on your application's platform.  (And if you are supplying this application to others, then THEY have the problem too.)

And there are still 2 alternatives in my original that you could use instead: fix the application to workaround the problem, and stay with Java 5.

---

> The bug exists in the Java 7's XSLT and in the latest Xalan

Have you considered the possibility that this is not a bug at all?  Maybe it is a fix for a previous bug or allowed behavior within the scope of the relevant specs, and your code is at fault for depending on the previous (buggy?) behavior.

Are there bug reports in the Java / Xalan bug databases for this bug?  What do the maintainers say?  Do they offer workarounds?  (These questions NEED to be asked ...)

Comment: The bug exists in the Java 7's XSLT _and_ in the latest Xalan.

Comment: If there are native incompatibilities between the two, it looks like I'm left with grabbing the specific classes I need and either replacing them in rt.jar or overriding them with extdir.

Comment: I documented it here (Feb 2012 comment): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2430

Answer (score 1):

It is *mostly* backward compatible, we just migrated some 1.4.x code to 1.6 (with and without recompiling, therefore binary and source) and that worked.

I suggest you to have a look at every major java version release as there are always some incompatibilities. Have a look at the [Java 1.6 compatibility with 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html) and if you are migrating some older versions of source / binary, check all the major java versions page to see if you fall in the incompatibilities.

Edit: in your question, you wrote that you want Hotspot 1.6 (the JVM) to run with JRE 1.5 ? You know the JRE includes the JVM, are you certain about what you just asked ?

Comment: I think the OP's aware of how the JVM works, and isn't asking about source / API compatibility. I understood the question as wanting to do something like replacing `rt.jar` in the 1.6 installation with one from the `1.5` installation.

Comment: @Inerdial Oh, that doesn't sound very safe. I hope he's not. Actually in the [Java 1.6 compatibility with 1.5 (point 8)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html) they state: "Java applications that specify -Xbootclasspath:<path to rt.jar> and request any resource files will fail since these resources now reside in a different jar file called resources.jar."

Comment: I think the transplant is intended to go the other way around than what that documentation means.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you compiled your code with a java 5 compiler, then yes, you can run it on a java 6 vm without issues.

Comment: I'm trying to run my Java 5 code with Sun's Java 5 _runtime_ with the Java 6 version of Hotspot.

Comment: hmm not sure if that is even possible. the hotspot isnt distributed as a separate lib as far as i know. its a part of the jvm